# I would like to add two tags in NLP to make it one

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

Im getting tokenized into two different operators when i give >= in my query

```
query = "sales by channel having sales >= 5M"
for i in query.split():
 we = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
 tagged = nltk.pos_tag(we)
 print([(word + tag) for word, tag in tagged if tag in ('NNP', 'VBD')])
```

Comment: [('sales', 'NNS')]
[('by', 'IN')]
[('channel', 'NNS')]
[('having', 'VBG')]
[('sales', 'NNS')]
[('>', 'NN'), ('=', 'NN')]
[('5M', 'CD')]     I want the operator ">=" into a single tag

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you just need to do (without any loop or extra tokenizing):

```
query = "sales by channel having sales >= 5M"
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(query.split())
```

Output:

```
[('sales', 'NNS'),
 ('by', 'IN'),
 ('channel', 'NN'),
 ('having', 'VBG'),
 ('sales', 'NNS'),
 ('>=', '$'),
 ('5M', 'CD')]
```

You automatically get the correct splits of your sentence with the necessary PoS tags, including `>=` counting as one unit.